# What’s the proper way to lead the powerline of a security camera from the front porch into the house?

Tags: wiring, security

I purchased a Wyze cam v3, and I plan to anchor it there (yellow arrow). Because this is a wired security camera. I must lead a powerline into the house.

I thought about leading the usb power line (a USB male head) into the house at the upper right corner of the wooden door. But I’m afraid repeated opening and closing of the door will eventually cut the powerline. What is the proper way to lead a wired security camera from the front porch into a house?

[image]

Comment: Wifi cameras don't offer security, bad actors carry wifi jammers.

Comment: Is there a light above the entry way?

Comment: Have you considered using a doorbell camera? There is already power going to the doorbell, so you wouldn't have to run any additional lines.

Comment: @SteveWellens There is! I’ve updated the photo to show more details

Comment: You have a window up there, would it maybe be easier to install the camera *inside* the house instead?  I don't know what the inside wall behind that door looks like.  Also might not work if it's frosted glass, hard to tell from this photo.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Inside the glass is definitely a good option to consider, but it has its own issues to work around because the glass can cause problems with cameras that use infrared light for night vision.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman sorry - In my experience glass in front leads to useless footage, more-so at night when most of the bad things happen and all your camera shows is white reflections of IR LEDs.

Comment: @Criggie I think that's only an issue if there's a gap between the camera and the glass.  If you can press the lens right up to the glass, you shouldn't get any reflections.  May depend on the model of camera and mount how well you can do that though.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman that would minimise reflections, but I've always wanted to put the camera at an angle, looking down a bit.   Its definitely worth a test - there's no cost or holes needed for trialing.

Answer (score 10):

A long masonry  bit, for that house.

The (evidently) wood framing around the transom window you have a yellow arrow on might or might not offer an easier route that works. You have to be very sure you are far enough into the wood to avoid trying to drill glass.

Comment: To clarify, you recommend drilling a hole somewhere on the wooden frame around the glass and feed the powerline (the largest part is the USB male end) into the house that way?

Comment: I mention that as a possible option, with drilling hole through the brick wall as the default option. If the USB is just for power (no communication/data on it) I would strongly consider "cut and splice" to drill a much smaller hole for the cable, rather than the large hole needed for a USB-type A connector to pass through. But that depends on you (it's 5 volts DC so not hazardous, but it takes some reasonable care.) Using a hardwired USB-A connector for power without providing a slim jack plug-in connector for easy pass-through is frankly a sign of **terrible design** by the camera maker.

Answer (score 10):

Route the cable upward, either exposed or concealed in regular or surface conduit, into whatever space is above the porch -- often an attic.

You could leave the conduit "unfinished," meaning without any junction box at its end, and let the cable drop out and route to the camera. Or, position a junction box at the end of the conduit and mount the camera to the junction box (or to a blank cover attached to the box). This may allow additional concealment of the cable.

Comment: Thank you Greg for your answer. Is there a youtube video for what you’ve described? I’m a beginner to home improvements projects. I don’t completely understand what you’ve described :/

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend a POE camera, they are not that much more and the power is carried in the cable so only one hole is required. There are many good sources for them. With that you will need a POE switch or a POE power injector. I would recommend the switch, they come in several varieties. I have several cameras connected that way and they work great. They do not drop out like the wifi ones did.

Comment: POE = Power over Ethernet.

Comment: You're right - POE is a good answer but still leaves OP with the problem of getting the wire into the home.

Comment: He could go through the frame with the appropriate size drill where he would have to then hide the wire inside possibly against the door frame trim. I had a similar problem so I put it in the 'ceiling' and then through the attic and fished it down to the switch. It was difficult but I got it in using Glow Rods and some help.

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned the camera was powered by a USB cable, consider using an adapter like this:

[image]
(via [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07P9SDD9M))

You would screw it into your existing light fixture.  The camera's USB cable would connect to the adapter, run through a small hole in the back side of the light fixture's globe and along the ceiling, then drop down the wall to your camera.  No holes required in your house.  Most of the cable will be hidden from view behind the light fixture, and the part that's still visible can be painted to match the ceiling/grout/trim.  There are much simpler and cheaper [adapters](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Socket-with-Outlets-White-R52-01403-00W/100184555) available that give you a standard power outlet, but the camera's AC adaptor may not fit well in an enclosed fixture like the one you have.

The drawback is that your light switch would now control both the porch light *and* the camera.  I would solve that problem by leaving the switch permanently "on" and installing a smart bulb that can be turned on/off remotely.  You can get a "[smart switch cover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0196M620Y)" that fits on top of your existing light switch.  It prevents the real switch from being turned off, while giving you a button that controls your smart bulb.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but make certain that the adapter has a legit UL certification. Many of these clever ideas are _NOT_ UL certified, and should there ever be an electrical issue with the house, causing a fire, if the insurance company finds it, they'll gleefully deny the claim. This one, in particular, makes _zero_ claims of meeting _any_ regulatory standards. _Caveat Emptor_

Comment: @FreeMan Always a good thing to keep in mind, and the reason I prefer to buy electrical stuff at a physical store (where they pre-screen their products) instead of online.  The specific products I listed were merely the first examples I could find with a good photo. I've seen a similar device that *was* UL listed at a local store, but that was long enough ago that I can't recall the name.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would run the wire directly up, through the ceiling and into the attic, but that placement depends on a host of things including "do you feel comfortable drilling holes into your house" and "do you have access to that area inside".

By far the *easiest* option is to simply buy an extension wire to run between the power supply and the camera, and run the wire through the top of the door. It may eventually wear out, but you can just replace the cable.

It looks like there are a couple of wires in the picture that that go into the house; on the left, over the porch light, is what looks like a phone line. If there is an accessible hole, you may be able to run a wire through there. You may also be able to re-use the doorbell hole, by drilling a small hole on the inside.

A final possibility is the outlet next to the door; as long as the power supply is small enough, you could buy a locking outlet cover, and safely plug the camera in there, locking the cover over top. You could even disguise the wire by using color-matched sanded caulk, and running the wire into a corner, along the grout. No drilling required, and it makes replacing or removing the camera super easy.

I recommend against drilling through the door or window frame, or through the bricks. Frames are not designed to have holes in them, and doing so could break the window, or crack the frame enough the door doesn't swing right. You might be able to poke a hole through the very edge, right up against the bricks, but it's a gamble. Drilling through bricks is safe enough, but the result will be a wire dangling from a hole in the wall, which doesn't look very good.